# onChange event not triggered when while clicking on SelectAllOption multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I've using `bootstrap multiselect` , getting data based on selected option. This filter data will works when `onChange` triggered but when trying to select all `onChange` not working:

```js
function getOptions(node, isFilter) {
    var isChanged = false;
    return {
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: isFilter,
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        filterPlaceholder: 'Search ...',
        nonSelectedText: node,
        numberDisplayed: 1,
        buttonWidth: '100%',
        maxHeight: 400,
        onChange: function () {
            alert('Changes');
            isChanged = true;
        },
        onDropdownHide: function (event) {
            if (isChanged) {
                filterData(node);
                isChanged = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
$('#myselect').multiselect(getOptions('myselect', true));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
<!-- Build your select: -->
<select id="myselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not at all clear what you're asking, what that code is meant to do, and what you're seeing instead. Please review [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder onChange even not triggered when using select all option

Comment: Perhaps it would help you get answers if you updated your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem. You can add external resources (Bootstrap) from a CDN like http://cdnjs.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap multiselect provide a function called "onSelectAll". This function will be use for select all option. You need to use onSelectAll function with onChange function.

```
function getOptions(node, isFilter) {
var isChanged = false;
return {
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: isFilter,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    filterPlaceholder: 'Search ...',
    nonSelectedText: node,
    numberDisplayed: 1,
    buttonWidth: '100%',
    maxHeight: 400,
    onChange: function () {
        isChanged = true;
    },
    onSelectAll: function() {
        isChanged = true;
    },
    onDropdownHide: function (event) {
        if (isChanged) {
            filterData(node);
            isChanged = false;
        }

    }
}
}
$('#DDLCity').multiselect(getOptions('City', true));
```

Comment: Then we need to add event for deselectall for too ?

Comment: Use following code for deselecting function of bootstrap multiselect.
            onSelectAll: function(e) {
                if(e){
                    isChanged = true;
                } else {
                    isChanged = false;
                }
            }

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap multiselect provides an event for this, and thats `onSelectAll`. You need to use `onSelectAll` when your `Select all` is checked. Here is the piece of code that is missing in your code:

```
onSelectAll: function() {
    alert("SELECT ALL");
    isChanged = true;
},
```

And below is the updated working version of your code:

```js
function getOptions(node, isFilter) {
  var isChanged = false;
  return {
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: isFilter,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    filterPlaceholder: 'Search ...',
    nonSelectedText: node,
    numberDisplayed: 1,
    buttonWidth: '100%',
    maxHeight: 400,
    onChange: function() {
      alert('Changes');
      isChanged = true;
    },
    onSelectAll: function() {
      alert("SELECT ALL");
      isChanged = true;
    },
    onDropdownHide: function(event) {
      if (isChanged) {
        filterData(node);
        isChanged = false;
      }

    }
  }
}
$('#myselect').multiselect(getOptions('myselect', true));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
<!-- Build your select: -->
<select id="myselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fire the event for Select All options, you can use:

```js
$('#example-onSelectAll').multiselect({
   includeSelectAllOption: true,
   onSelectAll: function(options) {
       alert('onSelectAll triggered, ' + options.length + ' options selected!');
   }
});
```

and for Deselect all option, you can use:

```js
$('#example-onDeselectAll').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    onDeselectAll: function(options) {
        alert('onDeselectAll triggered, ' + options.length + ' options deselected!');
    }
});
```

Reference:  [Bootstrap Multiselect](https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onDeselectAll)